# Javascript remove end of a directory in a string

Tags: javascript

I been looking into `split(), slice(), substring()` but im not sure they can do what i am looking for.

Basically I want to remove the last sub directory of a string for examble:

```
Computers/Hard-drive/5GB/Brand
```

I need to be able to remove the `Brand` out to something like `Computers/Hard-drive/5GB`

My solution is

```
var val = directory.split("/");
var result;
val.forEach(function (dir) {
     result = result+"/"+dir;
});
console.log(result);
```

This returns what I want. But I think this is bad code, I think there must be some way of doing this using only one line. What are other ways of doing this?

Comment: `var val = directory.split("/");val.pop(); result = val.join('/')`

Comment: what is the desired behaviour in the edge case (no slash at all, like `Computers`)?

Comment: Yes no slash in the edges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lots of options.

1. The regular expression approach
2. The `lastIndexOf` approach
3. The `split`/`join` approach

Personally I prefer the simplicity and lack of unnecessary intermediate objects that #2 provides.

### 1. The regular expression approach

...either [as shown by CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362721/157247) or a version using `replace` to replace all characters after the last `/`.

```js
let str = "Computers/Hard-drive/5GB/Brand";
str = str.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, "");
console.log(str);
```

This works just fine if there isn't any slash; it just returns the string unchanged.

### 2. The `lastIndexOf` version

```js
let str = "Computers/Hard-drive/5GB/Brand";
const index = str.lastIndexOf("/");
str = str.substring(0, index);
console.log(str);
```

Note that the above assumes there will be a slash. To not make that assumption, you need to add a guard in case `index` is `-1`:

```js
let str = "Computers/Hard-drive/5GB/Brand";
let index = str.lastIndexOf("/");
if (index !== -1) {
    str = str.substring(0, index);
}
console.log(str);

str = "Computers";
index = str.lastIndexOf("/");
if (index !== -1) {
    str = str.substring(0, index);
}
console.log(str);
```

### 3. The `split` and `join` approach

...[as shown by Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362735/157247). *(Removed mine when I saw hers, which is much more concise without being harder to read.)* Note that Nina's implementation also assumes there will be a slash, you'll need to do a check on the result of `split` (e.g., is it more than one long) to handle the case where there isn't one.

Comment: What is the difference from your regular expression than the @CertainPerformance ```str.match(/.*(?=\/[^/]+$)/)[0];``` thanks :)

Comment: @Luke - Using `match` means creating an unnecessary array (the result of `match`) vs. just directly producing the desired string.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a regular expression: match characters until lookahead matches `/`, followed by non-`/` characters, followed by the end of the string:

```js
const str = 'Computers/Hard-drive/5GB/Brand';
const result = str.match(/.*(?=\/[^/]+$)/)[0];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i had in mind. do you have any good regular expression tutorials in mind?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is useful, as is Google / Stack Overflow, and https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [**`String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [**`String.prototype.substring()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
var directory = 'Computers/Hard-drive/5GB/Brand'
var pos = directory.lastIndexOf("/");
var result = directory.substring(0, pos);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split, slice untile the item before the last one and join the array to a string.

```js
var string = 'Computers/Hard-drive/5GB/Brand',
    result = string.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The OP has since clarified that they do want to handle the case where there's no slash at all. Sadly that means we have to make your elegant one-liner a bit less elegant.